# Decision tree vs logistic regression feature importances

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-trees, logistic-regression, feature-importances

I have trained Logistic regression and decision tree in skearn on the same standardized dataset (binary classification).

Top important coefficients for the decision tree are (sorted by `tree.feature_importances_`):

[image]

And for logistic regression (sorted by `abs(logreg.coef_)`):

[image]

'Total day charge' is the most important coefficient for decision tree, but for logistic regression it is only the 5-th. Why?

'Total day charge' s approximately 35% more important than the next coefficient for decision tree, but for logreg it is almost 50% less important than the most important coefficient.

I can't imagine such optimal separating hyperplane, at least in 3 dimensions. As I can imagine, the biggest coeff in logreg must correspond to dimension, which is the best separating dimension itself.

Answer (score 0):

The difference in the importance of the `'Total day charge'` coefficient between the **decision tree** and **logistic regression** models is due to the way that ***each model learns from the data***. **Decision trees** and **logistic regression** are *two different machine learning algorithms*, and they have *different strengths and weaknesses*.

In general, **decision trees** are good at **learning complex, non-linear relationships** between the features and the target variable. They are **non-parametric models** that ***partition the feature space into regions that are separated by decision boundaries***, based on the values of the features. They can easily **capture interactions between features**, and they **don't require the data to be linearly separable**. This makes them well-suited to handling a wide variety of data, including data with many features and complex relationships between the features and the target variable. In **decision trees**, ***feature importance is determined by how much each feature contributes to reducing the uncertainty in the target variable***. This is typically ***measured by the amount of reduction in the Gini impurity or entropy*** that is achieved by splitting on a particular feature. In your case, it appears that the `'Total day charge'` feature was the ***most effective at reducing uncertainty in the target variable***, which is why it is considered the *most important feature by the decision tree model*.

On the other hand, **logistic regression** is a **linear model**, which means that ***it assumes that the relationship between the features and the target variable is linear***. It is a **parametric model** that ***estimates the coefficients for each feature in order to maximize the likelihood of the observed data***. This makes **logistic regression** less flexible than decision trees, but it also means that it can be **easier to interpret** and **understand**. **Logistic regression** models are typically simpler and **more interpretable than decision trees**, which can make them more useful for certain tasks. In **logistic regression**, ***feature importance is determined by the magnitude of the coefficients for each feature***. In your case, the `'Total day charge'` feature has a ***relatively small coefficient compared to the other features***, which is why it is **not considered as important** by the **logistic regression** model.

Given this difference in the way that **decision trees** and **logistic regression** learn from the data, it's ***not surprising that the two models would produce different results when applied to the same dataset***. It's worth noting that the *importance of a particular feature can vary depending on the model that is used*, and *different models can have different interpretations of feature importance*. This doesn't necessarily mean that one model is better than the other - it just ***reflects the different strengths and weaknesses of each model***.